# How do I mask "forbidden" chars in passwords in the mount command?

Tags: macos, terminal, password, mount

How do I properly mask/escape illegal characters like /:@\ in passwords added in the mount command?

The question arose in the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162544/how-to-restore-system-from-network-drive/162550#162550):

```
mount -t afp afp://adminname:password@ServerIPAddress/ShareName /Volumes/TimeMachine
```

The asking person had a backslash "\" in the password and the command didn't work. The solution were single quotes around the `afp...`-part.

Testing the whole scenario in a VM, I created an admin with a password similar to `aaaaa\@11111`, but I haven't been able to get the mount command working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) to protect the wonky characters in the password. Essentially each character (or byte of UTF-8) can be encoded as a `%` followed by two hex digits specifying the encoded byte. In your example, `\` -> `%5C` and `@` -> `%40`:

```
mount -t afp afp://adminname:aaaaa%5C%4011111@ServerIPAddress/ShareName /Volumes/TimeMachine
```

This worked in my test.