# diskutil shows Macintosh HD is missing (with Recovery HD occupying the entire space)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, fusion-drive, core-storage

So yesterday I managed to screw up my iMac 2012 (with Fusion Drive) by installing the Mac OS X 10.10.2 update... The installation stalled and when I tried to restore from an external drive using Time Machine I somehow managed to corrupt my hard drive... When I try to reinstall OS X it says I don't have any disks to install it to.

Anyways, now I'm running Disk utility on the command line at boot and I see the Macintosh HD volume has disappeared. Here is a screenshot of `diskutil cs list` and `diskutil list`:

[image: diskutil list]

It seems that the Recovery HD disk is occupying the entire disk space (3TB). How do I restore Macintosh HD with a new partition so I can finally reinstall OS X?

**Update 1**

After deleting 'Recovery HD' on the second disk erroneously here a second screenshot of `diskutil list`:

[image: diskutil list]

**Update 2**

So I delete the LVG and LG and went to Disk Utility... (See screenshot3) But my disks are in red and DiskUtility is forcing me to fix them... (Screenshot4) And when I do Im back to the same setup... (Screenshot5).

[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenshot4]
[image: screenshot5]

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Recovery HD doesn't occupy your whole 3 TB drive. It's disk1s3 in the diskutil listing with the common size of 650 MB.

Your Logical Volume Family and the Logical Volume vanished though.

- To rebuild it start to your Recovery HD or to Internet Recovery Mode, open Terminal and enter `diskutil cs list`.
- Copy the LVGUUID
- To recreate the LV enter `diskutil cs createVolume LVGUUID type name size`

  In your case probably `diskutil cs createVolume 7ABC--i_can't_read_the_rest jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100%`.
- Now reinstall Mac OS X or restore your system with the Time Machine backup.

**Update 1**:

Recovery HD doesn't exist anymore - it was deleted by accident. You have to rebuild your Fusion Drive from scratch now:

**Preparation:**

- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive)
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably Mavericks or Yosemite) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably Mavericks or Yosemite).

**Rebuild Fusion Drive**

- Booted to Internet Recovery Mode open Utilities → Terminal in the menubar and enter:
  `diskutil cs list` to get the CoreStorage listing.
- Copy the Logical Volume Group UUID, it's the first listed in the listing of `diskutil cs list`.
- Then delete the Logical Volume Group with `diskutil cs delete LVGUUID`.
  In your case: `diskutil cs delete 7ABC--i_can't_read_the_rest`
- Enter `exit` and quit 'Terminal'
- Open 'Disk Utility'. Enter 'Ignore' if you are asked to fix the drives.
- Choose your SSD and partition it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled),
  hit the Options button and choose GUID Partiton table and hit OK and Apply.
  Please check that the size is ~121 GB

  Example:

  [image: ssd]
- Choose your HDD and partition it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled),
  hit the Options button and choose GUID Partiton table and hit OK and Apply.
  Please check that the size is ~3 TB

  Example:

  [image: hdd]
- Quit Disk Utility and open Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list`

  Example (your disk identifiers and sizes are different of course: Your volume SSD probably has the Identifier disk0s2 and the size 121 GB and your volume HDD probably has the Identifier disk1s2 and the size 3.0 TB):

  [image: diskutil]
- Enter `diskutil cs create "Name" IdentifierSSD IdentifierHDD`
  In your case probably `diskutil cs create "Macintosh HD" disk0s2 disk1s2`.

  Copy the resulting LVGUUID

  Example:

  [image: cscreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs CreateVolume LVGUUID jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100%`.

  Example:

  [image: lvcreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs list`
  Check the size of your Logical Volume. It should have the size ~3.121 TB

  Example:

  [image: diskcslist]
- Quit Terminal
- Open 'Disk Utility' and check your newly created volume for errors
- Quit 'Disk Utility'
- Attach your external Time Machine backup drive or check this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162544/how-to-restore-system-from-network-drive) if you use NAS or another network share.
- Open 'Restore from Time Machine Backup'
- Choose the appropriate Time Machine backup and restore your system
- Reboot to your restored system.
- Unmount and detach your Time Machine backup drive
- Open 'Terminal' and enter 'diskutil list'
- Check if your 'Recovery HD' is listed.
- If your 'Recovery HD' is missing, usually reinstalling your current system with the latest available system installer (e.g. 'Install OS X Mavericks (10.9.5)' if Mavericks is currently installed) will recreate it without loosing any data. AFAIK [Recovery Partition Creator 3.8](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2014/07/recovery-partition-creator-3-8/) will NOT create a Recovery HD on CoreStorage volumes.
- After reinstalling the system with the latest available system installer open `App Store` and install the latest security fixes.

Comment: Hi klanomath. I tried what you said but got an "Error creating CoreStorage Logical Volume Group: The target disk is already in use by Core Storage (-69753)." I think this might be due to my latest attempt at erasing the Recovery HD. Can you look at my updated screenshots? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I thought it was in conflict with Macintosh HD. Did I screw up?

Comment: yes. I'm back to internet recovery mode. If I list with diskutil list I now see disk1 is Boot OS X (as in the first screen shot). However, I see the Recovery HD in the Disk Utility panel. What should I do now? Anyway to reconvert the Boot OS X disk to Recovery HD?

Comment: Thanks klanomath. I have the Recovery HD now. However, I'm getting "An error occured while adding a recovery system to the destination disk" when restoring from TM. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Once again...thanks for the help. I think I'm almost there. My problem is that when I go back to Disk Utility it says that I have to fix my disks (I now have 2 - HD and SDD). Look at my screenshots in my updated question. Where do I go from here? Do I partition the Macintosh HD it gives me when I fix them?

Comment: Ok new update... When restoring from Time Machine, i get an error saying "an error occured while adding a recovery system to the destination disk". I did all the steps you gave me. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't ignore the Time Machine error...it asks me to restart

Comment: No I get the error before restoration is complete

Comment: @sobremesa Then i recommend to Reinstall OS X (via internet) in Internet Recovery Mode. Probably Mountain Lion will be installed. Reboot and upgrade to the latest Yosemite. Then i would use Migration Assistent to import all apps and user data from the Time Machine backup

Comment: still same error... Quick question: I see you grayed out the first disk (disk0) in the 3rd screenshot. It seems to be the Recovery HD. Should I be seeing that? Because right now I only have 3 disks. disk0 is SSD, disk1 is HDD, and disk2 the OS X Base System

Comment: @sobremesa Please delete all your comments except the last one from time to time. the admins don't like extended commenting. I did the screenshots in a virtual machine. I had a system disk (disk0) and added two additional disks (disk1 and disk2) to create a fusion drive with those 2. Not to confuse anyone, i tried to mask disk0. If you have disk0 and disk1 now you have to continue with the step '• Enter `diskutil cs create "Name" IdentifierSSD IdentifierHDD`
In your case probably `diskutil cs create "Macintosh HD" disk0s2 disk1s2`.' in my answer and continue until the end.

Comment: @sobremesa don't get confused by the (masked) recovery disk in my example. Don't create a recovery disk manually! It will be created later automatically installing Mountain Lion/Yosemite OR by just reinstalling Yosemite after a successful time machine restore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20814/discussion-between-klanomath-and-sobremesa).