# How to restore system from SynologyRouter Time Machine?

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

I want to restore my system from a Time Machine backup which is on a SynologyRouter Time Machine network drive.

When I restart in recovery (Cmd-Opt-R) and try to restore from Time Machine backup, no Time Machine volume / drive is shown or found.

I followed the instructions provided in an earlier question, [How to restore system from network drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162544/how-to-restore-system-from-network-drive/162550#162550?newreg=fae93883293b4092af09c8074f7ddfee), and while all commands in the Terminal are being executed fine, when I get to Step 13 of the procedure outlined, the Mac still does not show or find a Time Machine volume.

Are there any alternative procedures available or anything else that may be needed to successfully complete Step 13 of the above mentioned solution?

Please note, I would prefer to not have to first perform a clean install, followed by Migration Assistant.

Answer (score 1):

To restore from a Time Machine backup on SynologyRouter, and probably any other Time Machine network drive, selecting the 'Other Server' option in the 'Select A Restore Source' screen will allow one to enter the proper network drive URL.
What is important, though, to enter the full URL, including the actually shared network folder name, not just the URL for the network server.