# Using a HDD for TimeMachine on both NAS and via USB

Tags: network, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, nas

Is it possible to have a HDD for TimeMachine and using it on a NAS? I'm running OpenMediaVault on an ARM-SBC on Linux. I want to be able to remove the drive from the NAS and plug it into the Mac in case I need to restore it.

The problem is, Linux can't really work with HFS+ Journaled file system which is needed for TimeMachine backups and Mac not creating TimeMachine backups (despite even mounting them natively) on ext4 drives...

Ultimatively the disaster I want to prevent is having the NAS and the Mac fail, and then having to setup the NAS all over again first, then being able to recover the Mac with the network-attached TimeMachine backup.

Isn't there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: I can see this as being fraught with difficulties - but also probably not necessary. You can restore directly from the NAS over your LAN - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162544/how-to-restore-system-from-network-drive

Comment: BTW, the chances of both failing at once are more towards 'house burns down' territory… for which you require off-site backups.

Comment: True, also I just found out you can just finish the setup on the mac, install ext4 drivers and then mount the single HDD. Good enough for me I guess.